# Правильно я решил задачу в условиях JS?

Tags: javascript, task

> Дано целое число, большее **999**. Используя одну операцию деления нацело
>   и одну операцию взятия остатка от деления, найти цифру,
>   соответствующую разряду сотен в записи этого числа.

```js
var a = +prompt("Введите число a больше 999", "");
a = Math.floor(a / 100);

var hundred = a % 10;

document.write("Сотни: " + hundred + "<br>");
```

Я глянул как решают эту задачу на паскале и учитывая что в JS нет строгой типизации такой вопрос.
Это решение верно или проблема была не в типизации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам код верный, но есть лишняя операция

```
var hundred = Math.floor(a % 10);
```

Можно заменить на

```
var hundred = a % 10;
```

`a` уже целое, и остаток от деления на 10 тоже целое число.

Зато с другой стороны в вопросе не сказано что у вас есть операция `Math.floor`...

Comment: Действительно, лишняя операция, не углядел.
Задачник рассчитан на несколько языков, но туда JS не входит.
Раздел в котором находится задача называется Integer.
Вот я и пытаюсь с int работать через Math.floor

Comment: @tranntus тогда всё верно, так как реально если есть типизация `int` то к целому числу приведёт за счёт неё, а в `javascript` только так.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы решил так:

```
let num = +prompt("Введите число a больше 999", ""); 
console.log(num % 1000 / 100 ^ 0);
```

Comment: let это вроде новый синтаксис, а мне положена пока только самая первая спецификация. 
Да и побитовых операторов я не знаю

Comment: объявите как var,побитовые операторы это основы в любом учебнике

Comment: так то оно так, не спорю
Я их использовал только в задачах к разделу "побитовые операторы"
Опыта в реальных проектах нет, так что не знаю их значимость и нужность.

Comment: Без округления как выше уже писали не обойтись,но два Math.floor в решении много...